# How to assign a channel to a parse object

Tags: android, parse-platform

How can I assign a channel to a Parse Object.Actually I am trying to assign different channel to each device in which the app is going to be installed,So that for each installation device will be separated.I tried to search tutorials I am new to parse.Every where channels are described with PF object.I dont know what is this.I just know ParseObject.How to assign channel to a parse object.If i have a declaration like this:

```
  ParseObject pObject=new ParseObject("Rotator");
```

Code for My Sending Data Method:

```
            po = new ParseObject("LatLang");
            po.put("imei_code", imei_code_of_device);
            po.put("latitude", Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
            po.put("longitude", Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
            po.saveInBackground();
```

Code for MyRecieving data method:

```
    po=new ParseObject("LatLng");
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("LatLang");
    query.whereEqualTo("imei_code", "357146054169800");
    query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject objectLatest, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                lat = objectLatest.getString("latitude");
                lang = objectLatest.getString("longitude");

                e1.setText(lat);
                e2.setText(lang);
                e3.setText(objectLatest.getObjectId().toString());
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Found the New Location:\nLatitude:" + lat
                                + "\nLongitude:" + lang + "\nObjectID:"
                                + objectLatest.getObjectId().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error was found\n" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("item", "Error: " + e.getMessage());

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: `new ParseObject("Rotator");` would make/open a class/table named Rotator.

Comment: Use this: `pObject.put("channels","Rotator");` **This will create a column named channels (if not present) and put a value Rotator in it** and to subscribe: `ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Rotator");`

Answer (score 0):

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: I want to send some data to only a particular device not to all devices.will it be this way??using channels?

Comment: You want to send push notification depending on user. Easy, just match the user_id and then subscribe to a particular channel according to it.  Or while registering you can send a key that you can use here for your good.

Comment: For that you have to subscribe different channels for different devices with some unique values. Then  ParsePush pushData = new ParsePush(); using pushData.setChannel("Here you have to pass the channel name") then only it ll be delivered to the particular user.

Comment: And How to subscribe?As Akash explained?

Comment: Yes, check my comment under your question.

Comment: Suppose i am sending the current location of the my friend's device only to my phone.how will I do.can you show some code wrt this?

Comment: You want to get location from one device and show it in another via Push Notification?

Comment: Take the receiver device phone number as subscribe it as a channel.Then  send the push notification by setChanne() method.Use sendInBackGround() method to send the push notification.

Comment: Okay and what about parseObject as I am sending the location using the parse object and how should I have to retrieve it back from parseCloud?

Comment: For that you have to create your ownclass in parse you have to save data in parse under that parse .It is basically a map for a particular file there must be an identifier or key so that you can query to parse to get that particular file

Comment: I included the code in my question.I am trying to do something like this.Now can you tell how will I implement subscribing

Comment: @PsyDuck yes I exactly want this.
get location from one device and show it in another via Push Notification

Comment: Yes @Akash I wanted this.and somebody here told me to do this using this mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParsePush pushData = new ParsePush();
po = new ParseObject("LatLang");
        po.put("imei_code", imei_code_of_device);
        po.put("latitude", Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
        po.put("longitude", Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
        po.saveInBackground(new SaveInCallBack(){
                              pushData .setChannel("your channel name");
                              pushData .sendInBackGorund();

                              });
```

Comment: SaveInCallback or SaveCallback? SaveInCallback is not found

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - The type new SaveCallback(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
  SaveCallback.done(ParseException)
 - po cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: ya inside that constructor override that done method..Inside the done method set the channel and send the data.

Comment: If I use set channel inside done then it gives error:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setChannel(String) from the type ParsePush

Comment: Error is at this line:

ParsePush.setChannel("your channel name");

Comment: How will I retrieve this.On the other side?

Comment: What is setmeassage or setdata?Error:Can not push untill set message or set data